# How transform days to hours, minutes and seconds in Python

Tags: python, time

I have value `1 day, 14:44:00` which I would like transform into this: `38:44:00`.

I've tried the following code:

`myTime = ((myTime.days*24+myTime.hours), myTime.minutes, myTime.seconds)`

But it doesn't work. I got this error message:

> 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'hours'

Comment: Question: did you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)? It's clear that `myTime` is a `timedelta` object

Comment: Yes, but I not found :/.

Comment: Sorry for my fool question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timedelta object doesn't have hours property. Only `microseconds`, `seconds` and `days`.

Use:

```
myTime = '%02d:%02d:%02d.%06d' % (myTime.days*24 + myTime.seconds // 3600, (myTime.seconds % 3600) // 60, myTime.seconds % 60, myTime.microseconds)
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and it works but the output is not quite accurate, for example, for `0 days 00:07:02.710529` I got `00:07:07`, is it because of the negligence of the `microseconds` in your code?

Comment: you should replace `//` with `%` in to calculate the seconds

Comment: Thanks @A.khou for pointing this out. I fixed it and included microseconds. This should work correctly now.