# Convert timedelta output into hours,minutes and seconds Python

Tags: python-3.x, timedelta

I need to convert a timdelta variable to hours, minutes and seconds, I managed to do so with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546514/how-transform-days-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds-in-python/33546642#comment104333990_33546642)

but the results were not accurate

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
startDateTime = datetime.now()
#Do some work
print(startDateTime)
endDateTime=datetime.now()
print(endDateTime)
diff = (endDateTime - startDateTime)
print('diff with microS',diff)
diff = diff - timedelta(microseconds=diff.microseconds)    
print('diff w/o microS',diff)
diff = '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (diff.days*24 + diff.seconds // 3600, (diff.seconds % 3600) // 60, diff.seconds // 60)
print('Heures de roulage ',diff)
```

in my example

```
diff with microS 0 days 00:07:02.710529
diff w/o microS 0 days 00:07:02
Heures de roulage  0:07:07
```

I don't understand why it added those 5 seconds **0 days 00:07:02** became **0:07:07**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line `diff = '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (diff.days*24 + diff.seconds // 3600, (diff.seconds % 3600) // 60, diff.seconds // 60)`
instead replace `//` by `%` 
==> 
`diff = '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (diff.days*24 + diff.seconds // 3600, (diff.seconds % 3600) // 60, diff.seconds % 60)`